# play powerpoint pps in a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, powerpoint, autoplay

I have seen some [examples](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/05/how-can-i-run-a-powerpoint-slide-show-from-a-script.aspx) that uses vbscript to play powerpoint pps files. Is it possible to play pps file in a `iframe` using javascript ?